# Calling a method stored in a delegate takes longer on the first call

Tags: c#, delegates, jit

```
private void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Func<int, int> f = (i) => i * 2;

    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareDelegate(f);

    Stopwatch dummy = new Stopwatch();

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    f(2); // Call 1
    sw.Stop();

    Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();

    sw2.Start();
    f(2); //Call 2
    sw2.Stop();

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("First Call: {0}, Second Call: {1}", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000, sw2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000));

}
```

In Reference to the code above, I used the RuntimeHelpers.PrepareDelegate method in order to pass the JIT compilations and prepare the native code prior to the first call. However "Call 1" still takes longer to execute than "Call 2".

Sample Run:

When calling DoSomething for the first time,
Call 1 takes 2.4 microseconds and Call 2 takes 0.4 Microseconds

When calling DoSomething a second time,
Call 1 takes 0.8 microseconds and Call 2 takes 0.4 Microseconds

How this could be explained.

Comment: These operations are far too fast to time in a meaningful way.  Processors are never fast when you do something for the first time, the TLB and L1 I-cache need to be loaded, that takes time.  You otherwise make a very traditional benchmark mistake, your measurement includes the cost of ensuring that the Stopwatch.Stop() method can be called for the first time.

Comment: Yes, I thought that would be the answer. Also i tried that with optimizations enabled and the program running without debugging. The two calls take approximately the same time.

Thank you @HansPassant